# How to create a pivot table in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table in Excel 2010 using this code below but can't seem to get it to work.

It goes as far as creating a new tab called 'PivotTable' but no data actually appears. The functionality I am trying use is I copy data from a report generated in excel into a tab on my pivot generator press a button and it creates the pivot table. This is a code I found on Excel Champs but the thread seems to have died with no answers to the questions.

```
Sub InsertPivotTable()
'Macro By ExcelChamps

'Declare Variables
 Dim PSheet As Worksheet
 Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

`'Insert a New Blank Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Data")

'Define Data Range
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PTable = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="DefectsPivotTable")

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="DefectsPivotTable")

'Insert Row Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DefectsPivotTable").PivotFields("Assigned to").Orientation = xlRowField.Position = 1
End With

'Insert Column Fields
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DefectsPivotTable").PivotFields("Status").Orientation = xlColumnField.Position = 1
End With



'Insert Data Field
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("DefectsPivotTable").PivotFields("Status").Orientation = xlDataField.Function = xlSum.NumberFormat = "#,##0".Name = "Revenue "
End With

'Format Pivot Table
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesPivotTable").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"

End Sub
```

Comment: First, comment out / remove `On Error Resume Next`. That way you'll see what (if anything) in the code isn't working. As it stands, this will just run through but not tell you where and why it may be failing. Then, provide a [mcve] describing *how* to use this macro, with sample data.

Comment: The syntax for Insert Row/Column/Data fields doesn't look correct.  You also use `PTable` twice rather than `PTable` and `PCache`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you were pretty close!  Try something like this.

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String

'Determine the data range you want to pivot
  SrcData = ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & Range("A1:R100").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create a new worksheet
  Set sht = Sheets.Add

'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
  StartPvt = sht.Name & "!" & sht.Range("A3").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:=SrcData)

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
  Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=StartPvt, _
    TableName:="PivotTable1")

End Sub
```

Just pass in your `LastRow` and `LastCol` as dynamic ranges, similar to the way you are doing it now.